# Unexpected output from C-program

Tags: c, gcc, netbeans-8

Thanks for your help earlier..
Here I am with a new problem facing the same output. scanf() is not working. I am using MACROs in it and this time format is correct LOL.. 
please have a look and tell me what am i doing wrong here.
i am trying to take two characters as input and test whether they are "uppercase or not" or "lowercase or not".
my program scans for ch1 but doesn't scan for ch2;
i tried flushing the input using "fflush(stdin);" but still the same.
when i printed the value of ch2 to see what it is taking in account it shows "10" that's where i tried to flush the input but still the same output.
so please have a look and please tell me my mistake.
I'll be very thankful.

```
       #include <stdio.h>
       #define UPPERCASE(x) {\
                             if(x>=65 && x<=90)\
                               printf("Uppercase letter\n");\
                             else printf("not Uppercase\n");}
       #define LOWERCASE(x) {\
                             if(x>=97 && x<=122)\
                               printf("LOWERCASE LETTER\n");\
                             else printf("not lowercase\n");}
       #define BIGGER(x,y) { \
                             if(x>y)\
                               printf("%d is biger\n",x);\
                             else printf("%d is bigger\n",y);}


       int main()
       {
            char ch1,ch2;
            int x,y;

            printf("enter a UPPERCASE LETTER\n");
            scanf("%c",&ch1);
            UPPERCASE(ch1);

            printf("enter a LOWERCASE LETTER \n");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%c",&ch2);
            LOWERCASE(ch2);


            printf("enter  two numbers\n");
            scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);
            BIGGER(x,y);
            return 0;
          }
```

Here my output

[image]

Comment: For starters, [stop doing that: `fflush(stdin);`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin). It invokes *undefined behavior*. You need to consume the newline from the input stream, one way or another. `" %c"` (note the leading space, useful for single-character reads) is a common way to do that after a previous formatted input request. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46166734/why-does-scanf-not-work-when-access-a-input-of-char-type-in-c).

Comment: yes it worked. but i still don't get it. please elaborate. why as you say a leading space or consuming a new line is necessary?

Comment: Did you *read* the linked question in my comment?

Comment: yes,  but still unclear. isn't it that scanf() just suppose to take a input. what a blank has to do in it?

Comment: [Try this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer).

Comment: FYI there exist methods of seeing if a character is uppercase - isupper() - and all manner of other similar checks

Comment: i know. but this program is not about to check the case of an alphabet, its about the use of MACROs.
thanks @WhozCraig i got it now.
I appreciate your help guys.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flushall()` function that clears all buffers associated with input streams, and writes any buffers associated with output streams.

`Flushall()` isn't C, but a vendor specific extension.

**OR**

Other alternative is to use space before `%c`

---

Example

```
char ch;
scanf(" %c", &ch);
```

The other problem is with the use of macro. Inside macro definition you are using same name as local variable `x` and `y` of main()

Comment: okay that space before %c worked but using same name in MACROs does really affect? bcos that part of the program worked fine.
what i don't get is..why a space before %c is necessary ?